# How to show all the databases in Hive using jlist in java swing application?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, hive, jlist

I'm trying to show my hive databases using java swing (jList) with image icon to display the databases present in hive. While doing this process, only one db name with imageicon is showing in the jlist. Can any one suggest me how to display all my databases with an image icon on it.

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "arunachalam", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "show databases";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String s1 = rs.getString(1);
            DefaultListModel dm = new DefaultListModel();
            dm.addElement(new ImgNText(s1, new ImageIcon("images/hive_db.png")));
            jList1.setCellRenderer(new Renderer());
            jList1.setModel(dm);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Exception");
    }
```

Comment: Just put `DefaultListModel dm = new DefaultListModel();` before the `while` loop .Also, set the renderer and the model of the list after the `while` loop .

Comment: Also, set the renderer and the model of the list after the while loop. you were saying about jList.setCellRenderer(new REnderer()) and jList1.setmodel(dm). I have to use these two lines after while statement?

Comment: Thanks Berger, it worked.